# Special reptiles - repeating shapes and fractals

Tags: geometry, fractals

Let me first explain what a reptile is.

> A reptile is a two-dimensional object, a shape, that can be dissected into smaller, equally sized copies of the same shape.

To illustrate this, see here a couple of reptiles:

[image: reptiles]

A shape is called an $n$-reptile, or $n$-rep for short, if the shape can be dissected into $n$ smaller, equally sized copies. So above you see a $2$-rep (recognize the shape? Yup, it's A4 paper! Could be any of the A-series in fact) a $3$-rep (a [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)) and a random $4$-rep.

Now obviously, if a shape is an $n$-rep, it's also a $n^2$-rep; simply dissect it once in $n$ pieces, and dissect every piece you made again in $n$ pieces. One can repeat this pattern to see that in fact, if a shape is an $n$-rep, then it must be an $n^k$-rep for integer $k\geq 1$. These dissections in $n^k$ pieces aren't very interesting though, since they're all based on the base case with $n$ pieces. This got me thinking, and so here's my question:

> Does there exist an $n$-reptile that is simultaneously an $m$-reptile with $n$ and $m$ coprime?

Comment: I assume you want to exclude the square, which is an $r^2$-reptile for any $r$, hence for coprime values like $4$ and $9$. Equilateral triangles too.

Comment: Apparently, it is an open problem that there exists $2$-reptiles that are also $3$-reptiles. Stated in [just above theorem 1.4](http://www.math.ust.hk/~yangwang/Reprints/reptile.pdf).

Comment: Yes @EthanBolker I inexplicitly meant to leave those out, since they're trivial cases

Comment: Do you allow mirrored tiles? Do you allow different sized tiles?

Comment: By "smaller, equally sized copies" I mean they cannot be mirrored, but rotated, and the size should be the same

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question; I suspect that's open in general. One comment, though: The Sierpinski triangle is not a reptile, since it's dimension is less than two. The "tile" in rep*tile* is intended to indicate that the shape should tile the plane.

Comment: @MarkMcClure [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile#Fractals_as_rep-tiles) states otherwise. Although the fractal dimension is not 2, it's still a twodimensional object, meaning, it's flat. Perhaps my stated definition is a little bit unclear.

Comment: That particular section has no citations, though. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rep-Tile.html) requires a rep-tile to be a polygon.

Comment: @vrugtehagel I think it's obviously a fairly loose term. As Rahul points out, sometimes you want to focus on polygons. In the reference that Simon points to, it's a more arbitrary shape. One might or might not want to include reflections, multiple sets, or different sizes. But *nowhere* have I seen the term include sets whose dimension is smaller than the ambient space. Even the first sentence in the Wikipedia article asserts that reptiles arise "in the geometry of tessellations". I would suggest that the author of that section was incorrect or, at least, did not properly state his context.

Comment: If you accept shapes with dimension < 2, a line segment is an $n$-reptile for any $n$.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with fractal dimensions, but I feel like siepinski's triangle is just 2-dimensional, and perhaps we should add "shapes with an area greater than 0" to avoid the cases that Rahul states one of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Viper](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/viper/) substitution tiling divides a particular triangle into 9 similar sub-triangles without reflection, in a non-trivial way.  The same triangle can also be divided into 4 similar sub-triangles without reflection, see the top half of the triangle in the rule image on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a Square, it can be divided into 4 smaller squares or 9 smaller squares,

So it is 4-rep and 9-rep.

4 and 9 are both coprime.